# Webcast module for drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I was searching for the webcast plugin for drupal but didnt find one.  Any idea regarding Webcast module for drupal??

thanks in advance

Comment: i dont understand why its being marked???

Comment: answer to  the questions is already given by the person.. Webcast is the best word i can use...  if there is any other simple word let me know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at FileField Podcaster or SWF Tools or if you're looking for something live check out Live Streaming http://drupal.org/project/vls